# Accessing dirty properties in Hibernate Interceptor's onFlushDirty method

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

As hibernate already calculates the dirty properties on an entity before flushing, is it possible to use that information in the onFlushDirty method of Hibernate Interceptor, so that it will be helpful in knowing which properties have been changed on the entity without comparing previous state values with the current state values